# Unable to do a simple rename file in ReleaseManagement during deployment

Tags: batch-file, release-management, ms-release-management

I have a problem that has been bugging me. 
I have a Visual studio 2013 solution that goes through Release management.

One of the release steps in Release management is running a simple batch file using the `Actions -> SxSBatchCommand` tool. This is a custom action that simply executes a batch file and the batch file executes a simple rename that goes like this:

```
rename "$(currentDir)\project.ev1.app.config" "project.exe.config"
```

Which basically takes a specific app.config and applies it in the deployed directory as the main config.

All this works well but because I don't like all the batch files in my project, I decided to delete them and to use the `WindowsOS -> Rename File or folder` tool

So I deleted the SxSBatchCommand and added the "Rename File or Folder" with parameters:

```
FileFolderName: project.ev1.app.config
DestinationName: project.exe.config
```

I also tried:

```
FileFolderName: $(currentDir)\project.ev1.app.config
DestinationName: project.exe.config
```

This failed during deployment with the message:

```
The following command failed with the exit code '1' : powershell -command ./ManageWindowsIO.ps1 -Action Rename -FileFolderName 'project.ev1.app.config' -DestinationName 'project.exe.config'
```

Any ideas why such a simple command wouldn't be working?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Can you run this exact command in powershell console ? You can also click on the button next to the command in the release log to grab a better detaild log whith explanation what went wrong .
The file could be in use , or without proper permissions  for modification , you can look for the agent's logs in the target machine .

By the way if you are trying to make a file changed to the name of a configuration file for a win service or want to use transformation in a non web application you can use slow cheetah to accomplish it .

Comment: All of these are sensible solutions and I thought of them too, but I don't have access to the build server to run the command myself or to look at the logs. So the target machine is kind of a black box.
I just assumed since running the powershell command from the batch file works, so should the command from the RM.